# Everyday German in conversation

Tags: standard-german

I want to read some conversation in places like [a shop](http://theenglishspace.com/useful-english/shopping/clothes/conversation.html), a restaurant, in a class between student and teacher, college and other occasions. It should be something like this English website:

[Everyday English in Conversation](http://www.focusenglish.com/dialogues/conversation.html)

I'd prefer conversations that are not very short and old-fashioned words are not used in them.

Answer (score 3):

Deutsche Welle Online might be a good place to start. There are audio clips to listen to as well as worksheets to print out. They offer a variety of courses that address language from everyday speech, news, business, travel, mystery, etc. with "Deutsch - warum nicht?", "Wieso nicht?", "Marktplatz?", "Radio D", and others.


Here is their main link to choose your native language: [DW Deutschkurse](http://www.dw.de/dw/0,,2547,00.html)

Here is their link for English: [DW Deutschkurse Englisch](http://www.dw.de/dw/0,,2469,00.html)

I think that might be what you're looking for. And DW is certainly a reputable source.